# AT89S8253 and Keil ULINK2 debugger connection?

Tags: atmel, jtag, 8051, keil, swd

I'm trying to connect AT89S8253 with Keil ULINK2. But the documentation is nil about 8051 controllers. As per the web, the pin connection is this.
ref: http://www2.keil.com/coresight/coresight-connectors#10pin

[image: ULINK2 pinout]

ULINK2 supports the ATMEL family of 8051 controllers (reference: http://www.keil.com/dd/). ATMEL uses SPI pins for the ISP programming. What is the correct pin connection?

---

[Updated - Original question referred to AT89**C**8253, but OP has confirmed this was a typo and AT89**S**8253 was intended.]

Comment: (a) "I'm trying to connect AT89C8253 with Keil ULINK2" - Why *exactly* do you believe that the ULINK2 supports that *specific* chip? Please supply a link to a webpage which supports that claim. (b) "It supports the ATMEL family of controllers" - What is the "it" in your sentence? Atmel produce various different families of MCUs, so your claim that "it" supports all of them (no matter what "it" you are referring to) seems unlikely. || I think I understand your confusion, but before writing an answer, I want to make sure I understand where *exactly* you are reading those claims.

Comment: Edited as per your comments.

Comment: Your link seems to show that *some of* Keil's tools support some of Atmel's 8051 derivatives, but it does not seem to list the ULINK2 as a supported interface for them, rather it lists software tools from Keil and adapters from other vendors.

Comment: @Basheer - I realised (late into writing my answer), that you seem to have mentioned a strange (non-existing?) model number - AT89**C**8253. Although there were many AT89Cxx devices, the AT89C8253 does not appear as a *genuine* part number in any searches I have done. Therefore I have replied as if you had meant to list the AT89**S**8253 device. As Chris Stratton explained above (+1), being listed in the Keil Device Database just means that *some* Keil tools support *some* Atmel devices. The critical details are listed in the specific database entry for each device.

Comment: @samGibso Yes. That was a typo. I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR - Unfortunately you can't use the ULINK2 with the Atmel AT89S8253.**

You said:

> ULINK2 supports the ATMEL family of 8051 controllers (reference: http://www.keil.com/dd/).

Unfortunately you have misunderstood what that webpage shows. The "Legacy Device List" (it used to be called "Device Database" until MDK5 was released) is described by Keil [here](http://www.keil.com/dd/whatisdd.asp) where they say:

"The Device Database is a searchable database that contains information about the various microcontrollers supported by software development tools from Keil.
[...]
The online Device Database **entry for each device explains which features are supported**." <sub>[My emphasis]</sub>

Therefore you can see that having an entry in the old Device Database does *not* mean that the ULINK2 is supported by that device. It just means that *some* features of the Keil range of software development tools are supported by that device. You have to view the specific webpage for *that* device, to see *which* features (e.g. ULINK2) are supported.

The Device Database page for the [Atmel AT89S8253](http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/3784.htm) does not mention the ULINK2 at all. That *lack* of mentioning ULINK2 is telling you that ULINK2 is not supported with that target device (I will explain why below). Whereas the Keil CA51 compiler kit *is* supported on that device, since this *is* listed.

Compare that with, for example, the Device Database page for the [NXP (Philips) P89LPC952](http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/3936.htm) which specifically lists:

"JTAG Debuggers
[...]
ULINK2"

---

Here is why the ULINK2 is not compatible with the Atmel AT89S8253:

As you can see in the [Atmel AT89S8253 datasheet](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/atmel/at89s8253_ds.pdf) from the Keil website, there is no mention of a JTAG (or SWD) interface on that IC. However as described here in the [ULINK2 webpage discussing the initialisation sequence with 8051-type devices](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulink2/ulink2_hw_start_sequence.htm), the ULINK2 uses a JTAG (or SWD) interface with the target device:

[image: ULINK2 start sequence with 8051-type devices]

However the [P89LPC952 datasheet from the Keil website](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/philips/p89lpc952_954.pdf) (which I mentioned as an example of a different 8051-style device earlier) shows that it *does* have a JTAG-style (really SWD) debug interface:

[image: NXP P89LPC952 datasheet - debugger interface]

This explains why that device *is* compatible with the ULINK2 and why its listing in the Device Database *does* mention the ULINK2 (unlike the listing for the Atmel AT89S8253).

---

In summary: The Atmel AT89S8253 does not have the required JTAG/SWD debugger interface to connect to a ULINK2, and Keil do not claim that the ULINK2 is compatible with that target device. Some other 8051-type device do have a JTAG/SWD debugger interface e.g. the NXP (Philips) P89LPC952.